# JavaScript iterate through assign values of array to object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have object with dynamic quantity of properties and array with dynamic quantity of items in it. I need to iterate through both of them and assign values of array to property of object.

```
var obj = {
  property1: null,
  property2: null,
  .....
};

var array = ["some value1", "some value2"...];
```

**Must be**

```
var obj = {
  property1: "some value1",
  property2: "some value2",
  .....
}
```

Comment: object property name doesn't have any order

Comment: @PranavCBalan: Well, they do in ES2015 and above, but it's not a useful thing to do anything with, really. I certainly wouldn't rely on it for something like the above.

Comment: @ qr11: How do you determine that the value at `array[0]` is for `property1`, etc.? Hopefully not by the order of the properties in the object?

Comment: Do the property names actually have numbers in them? You can use a string value to get/set a property using an array syntax: `obj["property" + integerVariable]`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  By order in array

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : thanks for the info :)

Comment: @qr11 : is there any relation between object property name and array index ??

Comment: @qr11: "By order in array" tells us nothing. Let me ask the question differently: How do you know it's `obj.property1` that should receive `value[0]`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : I think property name related with the index (`index + 1`)

Comment: @qr11 well what relation? you can't get "first property of object". Any property of object may be first.

Comment: @Maxx: See the second comment above (but again, I wouldn't rely on property order for this).

Answer (score 0):

If you **literally** have `property1`, etc., then it's quite straightforward, because we can use the array index and brackets notation to build the property name from that index (plus one):

```js
var obj = {
  property1: null,
  property2: null
    //.....
};

var array = ["some value1", "some value2"/*...*/];
array.forEach(function(value, index) {
  //  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv------ string concat to build the property name
  obj["property" + (index + 1)] = value;
  // ^------------------------^----- brackets notation to refer to the property
  //                                 using a runtime-defined name
});
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer.
If name of property in dynamic then,

```js
var obj = {
  property1: null,
  property2: null,
};

var array = ["some value1", "some value2"];

var i=0
for (var index in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
    obj[index]=array[i];
  }
  i++;
}
console.log(obj);
```